# Hide form field until earlier field is filled?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, css

I have a registration form that is split.  I am looking for a method, preferably using css3, that will allow me to hide a form field until a particular field is validly completed.

For example:
I request "Group Name".  When Group Name field is filled with a valid group name, meaning one which exists in a database or xml file (this part requires js, and a dropdown is not an option), then the second field: "Group Password" will appear.

I'm using html5 and css3.  I'm willing to use javascript if absolutely necessary.  Thanks.

---

I imagine that I could use something like this:

`document.getElementById("groupname").disabled = true`

but I am unsure of how to trigger it.  Perhaps employing an html5 validation could act as a trigger?

Comment: Why are you avoiding JavaScript?

Comment: There's currently no selector that distinguishes between an empty, and a filled-in, `input` element ([so far as I'm aware, at least](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/)); so JavaScript is required for this.

Comment: If I must, then us will have to suffice.

Comment: Why bother to hide the group password field? It isn't going to take up vast amounts of space, and making it appear only when a group is selected is just going to be a case of "Surprise! We want a password too!" (surprises are bad when asking people for their data). (It also means that you'll be exposing the list of possible groups).

Comment: That was just an example.  More likely, I would want the remainder of the form to appear after validating the group password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a glance something like the following seems to work:

```
:invalid ~ .test {
    display: none;
}

<form>
    <input type="text" required/> <!-- Displayed -->
    <fieldset class="test">
        <input type="text"/>  <!-- Hidden until top input is filled -->
    </fieldset>        
</form>
```

Should be able to handle simple cases.  This could then be enhanced using the `setCustomValidity` call to wire in your validation.

Comment: That's [a very nice workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vEDWt/)! (My JS Fiddle unwraps the the `input` so they're siblings, because I was curious as to why you wrapped it.) +1

Comment: I wrapped it in the `fieldset` so that would serve as the container for all of the controls that would be displayed after validation. I may have been thinking I would develop a richer sample but then just got lazy :).